# Is it possbile to use bitbucket in a legacy code Visual Studio 2003 environment?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2008, bitbucket, smart-device

one of my projects is a smart_device application for an old Motorola device running WindowsCE, it only compiles in VS2008 and is doing fine so far. But: I want to switch from (old)svn to bitbucket like I did with all the rest of my projects. I'd like to use an VS integrated BB client like I do now with my other projects in  VS 2017

I found this: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yysun.GitSourceControlProvider and will give it a try. Is there any other plugin or has anyone else did something like this before?

thx
Florian

Answer (score 0):

I think that you shouldn't just use a small subset of all the great features that git provide to you just to stick to the really beloved VS user rule "I want all my tools in Visual Studio" (support in VS>=2012 is poor and painful -- too much right click to see history and changes and not understanding history, for example--).

I highly advise you to test [GitExtensions](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions) which is really feature rich/complete and is not dependent of a specific version of VS.

You will gain (not exhaustive list):

- git reflog support
- git stash management
- partial staging of file (very convenient)
- better git rebase support
- better git reset
- git clean
- support of " force with lease"
- better history navigation (with a beautiful display)
- Build server integration
- interactive rebase (with fixup/squash support)
- better "blame" support
- git worktrees support

...and a lot of other goodness.

With all that you will be able to become a git master ;)

Comment: Hey, you are totally right that it doesn't have to be in VS. I'm using Sourcetree in this case, but I just wanted to know if there is a way. Also: I don't need to become a master, I just need to store my code ;)